# Homebrew- impossible to install postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, openssl, homebrew, oh-my-zsh

I am stuck in the installation process of pg, making circles with the same issues, and couldn't resolve them.
I brew install libpq, then brew install openssl@1.1 then pg, and the exit error goes back to ask me to reinstall OpenSSL.
I have several Rails projects where PG used to work fine. I updates homebrew a few days ago and my configuration is a total mess.
My system is Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6. What do you advise to clean and start again with a proper configuration? (I am far from being a command line expert..)
Thanks for all recommendations!

Here is the mkmf.log I get when the installation of pg fails:

```
find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- no

--------------------

checking for libpq per pkg-config... -------------------- no

"pkg-config --exists libpq"
| pkg-config --libs libpq
=> "-lpq\n"
"clang -fdeclspec -o conftest -I/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0/x86_64-darwin18 -I/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -I/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib -L. -L/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib     -lruby.3.0   "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */

"clang -fdeclspec -o conftest -I/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0/x86_64-darwin18 -I/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -I/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib -L. -L/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib     -lruby.3.0 -lpq  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */

| pkg-config --cflags-only-I libpq
=> "-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.Internal.sdk/usr/local/include\n"
| pkg-config --cflags-only-other libpq
=> "\n"
| pkg-config --libs-only-l libpq
=> "-lpq\n"
package configuration for libpq
incflags: -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.Internal.sdk/usr/local/include
cflags: 
ldflags: 
libs: -lpq

--------------------

find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- no

"clang -E -I/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0/x86_64-darwin18 -I/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.Internal.sdk/usr/local/include -I/Users/rougnaux/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32  -fno-common -pipe   conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'libpq-fe.h' file not found
#include <libpq-fe.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libpq-fe.h>
/* end */
```

Comment: This may not be your expected answer, but I suggest you to consider using docker to manage tools like DBs.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using an installed instead? https://www.postgresql.org/download/

Comment: thanks for your answer @bryanfeller, I tried but still stuck in those weird loops